# How to export OSM maps given the bounds?

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping, extents

I have a map application where I use all kinds of OSM maps as background.

- http://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- http://{a-c}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- http://{a-c}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
- http://{a-c}.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.png

Is there a way to extract a part of the OSM map given the bounds?

I looked [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Retrieving_map_data_by_bounding_box:_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fmap) and I tried this:

```
http://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/api/0.6/map?bbox=-10,-10,10.10
```

But it didn't work.

I want to extract the part of the map that is within those bounds and get it returned as an image.

Comment: Most probably your bounds are too large. And I don't think that the servers listed have an API in the background. Note that the API returns raw nodes, ways and relations, while you are probably seeking for rendered tiles.

Comment: @AndreJ Yes, I am seeking for rendered tiles. I'm sorry if I didn't mention it. Would you please point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587690/jtiledownloader-gets-forbidden-from-mapnik and http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

Comment: investigate the static api https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/static-maps-api/ (the limit for pixel range is 8192 x 8192)

Comment: See also https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper

Comment: Rather than hammer OSM's and other tile servers repeatedly (which will likely cause problems further down the line) it might be worth looking at https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/ - generate your own tiles, in whatever style you want, for whatever area you want.